# Tail/forward recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

I dont understand why this is forward recursion:

```
int count(int x) {
    if(x<=0) return 0;
    return 1 + count(x - 1);
}
```

It's a question on a practice exam, and the answer is that its forward recursion. Why is this the case? How could I distinguish between the two?

Comment: practice question part 2 - how do you make it tail recursive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [tail recursion vs. forward recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042954/tail-recursion-vs-forward-recursion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing an addition after calling yourself.  Tail recursion means absolutely *nothing* can be after

If you understand the implementation, it's clear why.

Say we call `count` for the first time from `main`, which is at [program counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) `0xAAA`.  It then does most of its method.  We'll say the recursive call to count is at `0xBBB` for this stack frame.  If you're using tail recursion, when calling itself, it can set the return address as `0xAAA` (just go straight to the code that called me).  If it's doing *anything* after, it must set the return address as `0xBBC` (the address of the addition).  Because it doesn't need stack frames to store return addresses, it's also much easier to transform the recursion to iteration.  When `count` calls itself, it can just jump to the beginning of the method.

The solution (to the trivial example) is to build up the result in another parameter:

```
int count(int x, int res) {
  if(x<=0) return res;
  return count(x - 1, res + 1);
}
```

Note we do nothing after.

Comment: It's indeed not very clear as it's both in the return statement. But the very last call is `1 + result_of_recursion`, and not the recursion itself.

Comment: In addition to where the method returns to, it can also optimize away adding stack frames, correct?

Comment: @Mark, true, I'll add a note about that.

Comment: Thats weird I thought I added a comment here..anyway I said that I had no idea what you did in your example. Why use addresses and program counters and complicate this even more? Anyway you can do a comparison of tail recursion and forward recursion or come up with a clearer (more beginner-ish) explanation?

Comment: @fprime, the beginner explanation is just that you're doing something (addition) after the recursive call, so it can't be tail recursion.

Comment: @Mathew Even though function doesn't traverses back the stacks, but it expands creating new stack for every recursive call, thus consuming a lot of space. Iteration saves us from creating new stack frame for each call. Does tail recursion only saves us in memory returns from one stack to other? If so, shouldn't we try to use iteration at the places where we can?

Comment: @Sanjeev, I don't really understand your question, and it seems like it should be asked separately.  There is only one call stack (not stacks).

Answer (score 4):

Did you look at [this SO question, tail vs forward recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042954/tail-recursion-vs-forward-recursion)?

Matthew has the answer,and the long form would be that:

```
int count(int x) {
  if(x<=0) return 0;
  return 1 + count(x - 1);
}
```

can be written as (and is expanded as something like):

```
int count(int x) {
    if(x<=0) return 0;
    int tmp_result = count(x - 1);
    return 1 + tmp_result; // e.g. recursion is not last
}
```

Comment: Ya I saw this but the syntax was confusing