# "Default values" for Haskell function?

Tags: haskell

Is there any way that input values to a function can be pre-defined so that a user doesn't have to define them each time?

For example, assuming I had a function "zr" which returned a list zeros of size n, such that:

```
zr 1 = [0]
zr 5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And so on.

My current way of implementing it is:

```
zr :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
zr x y
    | length x == y = x
    | otherwise = zr x++[y]
```

But this isn't particularly elegant as every time I call zr I need to include an empty list as a parameter:

```
zr [] 5
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good way of implementing the requirement. If you want a nicer API, keep the implementation and write an additional wrapper function that supplies the extra argument. Don't compromise your business code for the sake of the API.

Comment: @KilianFoth It doesn't implement the requirement. It puts copies of `y` in the result and `y` is not expected to always equal `0`. Actually it doesn't even compile. Changing the recursive case to `zr (x ++ [0]) y` makes it work, but it's still inelegant and inefficient (appending at the end -- although prepending would work just as well -- and recomputing `length` at every step) and we have `replicate` for this.

Comment: Haskell list comprehensions often simplify things and can be brief.

zr = \n -> [ (0) | i <- [ 1..n ] ]  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

zr 1 = [0]  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

zr 5 = [0.0.0.0.0]

Comment: Point free (no variable parameters) would  be >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
zr = flip take $ repeat 0   >>>>>>>>> zr 5 produces the same result

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is *partial application*:

```
zr' :: Int -> [Int]
zr' = zr []
```

If `zr` is a function that takes a list and an integer, then `zr []` is a function that takes only an integer `n` and returns `zr [] n`.

In your case, `zr'` is obviously a "temporary" function (you don't want anyone accidentally calling `zr' [1] 4`), so you might as well define it locally:

```
zr :: Int -> [Int]
zr = zr' []
  where
     zr' :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
     zr' x y
         | length x == y = x
         | otherwise = zr' x++[0] y
```

Comment: Thanks, had thought of this, but was wondering if there was any way I could avoid having to write a second function.

Comment: I don't think it is possible - you'll have to introduce a second binding *somewhere*, since `zr` and your desired function are two different functions.

Comment: Aaah thanks, didn't know you could define a function locally!

Comment: @Dario - you're welcome! This sort of pattern is usually used in FP textbooks when dealing with recursion. I'd like to add that if your function is a "classic" recursion function - you can probably implement it using a higher-order function (`fold`,`map`,`filter`). Try is as an exercise!

Comment: Also note that `zr = flip replicate 0`

Comment: Edit: original version didn't compile. Thanks @raymonad

Comment: I think it should be noted that forward-recursion like in this answer and OP isn't feasible for the task, as I showed in my post below; forward-recursion is in most cases much longer and harder to read and run than backwards-recursion.  
(See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042954/tail-recursion-vs-forward-recursion)

Answer (score 7):

Not a Haskell pro myself, but I don't know a way besides defining a shorthand function (`zz n = zr [] n`).

In your concrete case there however is another solution:
You shouldn't loop the output through parameters, use the return value as means of recursion:

```
zr 0 = []
zr n = 0:(zr (n-1))
```

This will result in `0:0:[]` for `zr 2`, which evaluates to `[0,0]`.

Your version is very ineffective because it counts the length of the list on every step, keeps the end value around for no reason (you can decrement it and have 0 as end point) and also have a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want there are three options:

1. Passing a record type with function arguments, and defining "defaultParameters" with default values for these arguments ([see example in System.Process module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.0.1.1/docs/System-Process.html))
2. If you want to allow for just a single optional function parameter, you might consider using `Maybe` datatype, and pass `Nothing` if default is good enough.
3. If you want to have a *local defaults* that depend on scope, then use GHC extension [ImplicitParams](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#implicit-parameters). It will let you define defaults for a given code section, that are then used by everything in scope of this section.