# Removing element of list with forward recursion

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm writing a program which remove first element which fit to predicate eg.

```
remove' (fun x -> x = 2) [1;3;2;4;2] => [1;3;4;2]
```

and the problem is: how to write it with foward recursion? Is it possible? With tail recursion it is not a problem. I just add next elements to acc if they are not fit to predicate.

I was thinking about

```
List.fold_right,
```

but maybe is there different way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "forward recursion". Tail recursion defines a special kind of recursion, that occurs in a tail position. When you want to refer to a recursion that is not in a tail position, you call it "non tail recursive"

In the code you've specified there is no recursion at all. So, I would suggest you first of all to try to write `remove_if` function and try to figure out whether it is tail or non-tail.

### Update

I usually try no to solve homework for others, but at this case I will give a little kick start, by providing you with the most common definition of `remove_if` function:

```
 let rec remove matches = function
    | [] -> []
    | x :: xs when matches x -> remove matches xs
    | x :: xs -> x :: remove matches xs
```

There are two occurrences of recursion in this function:

```
| x :: xs when matches x -> remove matches xs
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            last expression - 
                            tail recursion

| x :: xs -> x :: remove matches xs
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  not the last - 
                  non tail recursive
```

So, last case needs some clarification: before the `x` can be prepended to the result of `remove matches xs` the latter expression needs to be evaluated. That means that computer needs to store `x` somewhere, to wait until `remove matches xs` is evaluatd.

So, no the fun part, you have a non-tail recursive version. Now, try to implement it tail recursively. Have `fun`!

Comment: I have read "foward recursion" on stackoverflow. Sorry if i'm getting wrong. 

The point is, that I have to write 'non tail recursive' and 'tail recursive' remove function. As I said, algorithm of 'non tail recursive' is problem for me. I have no idea how to make it works.

Comment: actually, I think that you should first try to write any implementation of the `remove_if` function. (The usual definition is actually non tail recursive, so it is harder to write tail recursive). And, as far as I understand, you can't use library functions to write `remove_if`, you need to use recursion

Comment: ok, since you're lost in terminology, I showed you an example of trivial _non_ tail recursive implementation.

Comment: A fold is sufficient, it's just `let remove_if p l = List.fold_right (fun e a -> if p e then a else e::a) l []`. Of course this is not the remove-only-one operation that the OP asks for. (That's also possible with `fold_right`, but ugly.)

Comment: But I'm little confused. I thought that recursion is calling method by itself and tail-recursion is when we are using acc to store results. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042954/tail-recursion-vs-forward-recursion?rq=1

Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: using accumulator is one particular method of achieving tail-recursion, the are other, e.g., continuation passing.

Comment: I add answer. ivg's solution was great, but it removes all occurrences of element in list. I had remove only first one.

Answer (score 0):

**ivg** solution helps me a lot, but I needed to upgrade it a little. My answer is:

```
 let remove' p xs =
   let rec remove_guard p xs g =
      match xs with 
        [] -> []
      | hd::tl -> if (p hd && g = 1) then remove_guard p tl 0 
                  else  hd::remove_guard p tl g
 in remove_guard p xs 1
```

Maybe not the best, but it removes only one element.

Thanks guys for help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not bad, but it can be done better, instead of continuing to recurse after the first match with guard flag (btw, there is a `bool` type for this), you can just choose not to recurse at all, as the result is already ready

Comment: You have right. You are my hero! :D Thanks again! It is not only about homework, but I really like functional programming (I'm programming in Python, which has poor functional, but still programming.) and it helps me to develop my skills.